# What is wrong with my code? I can't insert data into major, minor, and register tables, i am using Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the code used to create my database and tables, and all the insertions that I have so far

**below is all my code:**

```
-- Create Tables
drop database university;

create database university;

use university;

CREATE TABLE students
(
    ssn     integer,
    snum    integer,
    name    varchar(10),
    gender  varchar(1),
    dob     datetime,
    c_addr  varchar(20),
    c_phone varchar(10),
    p_addr  varchar(20),
    p_phone varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn),
    UNIQUE (snum)
);

CREATE TABLE departments
(
    code    integer,
    name    varchar(50),
    phone   varchar(10),
    college varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (code),
    UNIQUE (NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE degrees
(
    name            varchar(50),
    level           varchar(5),
    department_code integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, level),
    FOREIGN KEY (department_code) REFERENCES departments (code)
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
    number          integer,
    name            varchar(50),
    description     varchar(50),
    credithours     integer,
    level           varchar(20),
    department_code integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (number),
    UNIQUE (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (department_code) REFERENCES departments (code)
);

CREATE TABLE register
(
    snum          integer,
    course_number integer,
    regtime       varchar(20),
    grade         integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (snum, course_number),
    CONSTRAINT register_student_fk FOREIGN KEY (snum) REFERENCES students (snum),
    CONSTRAINT register_courses_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_number) REFERENCES courses (number)
);

CREATE TABLE major
(
    snum  integer,
    name  varchar(50),
    level varchar(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (snum, name, level),
    CONSTRAINT major_student_snum_fk FOREIGN KEY (snum) REFERENCES students (snum),
    CONSTRAINT major_degree_level_fk FOREIGN KEY (name, level) REFERENCES degrees (name, level)
);

CREATE TABLE minor
(
    snum  integer,
    name  varchar(50),
    level varchar(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (snum, name, level),
    CONSTRAINT minor_student_snum_fk FOREIGN KEY (snum) REFERENCES students (snum),
    CONSTRAINT minor_degree_and_level_fk FOREIGN KEY (name, level) REFERENCES degrees (name, level)
);


-- INSERTIONS


-- select * from students;

-- Insertion Record for students table.
insert into Students values
( 1001,  654651234, 'Randy' ,'M', '2000/12/01' , '301 E Hall' , 5152700988 , '121 Main' ,7083066321);
insert into Students values
( 1002,  123097834, 'Victor' ,'M', '2000/05/06' , '270 W Hall' , 5151234578 , '702 Walnut' ,7080366333);
insert into Students values
( 1003,  978012431, 'John' ,'M', '1999/07/08' , '201 W Hall' , 5154132805 , '888 University' ,5152012011);
insert into Students values
( 1004,  746897816, 'Seth' ,'M', '1998/12/30' , '199 N Hall' , 5158891504 , '21 Green' ,5154132907);
insert into Students values
( 1005,  186032894, ' Nicole' ,'F', '2001/04/01' , '178 S Hall' , 5158891155 , '13 Gray' ,5157162071);
insert into Students values
( 1006,  534218752, 'Becky' ,'F', '2001/05/16' , '12 N Hall' , 5157083698 , '189 Clark' ,2034367632);
insert into Students values
( 1007,  432609519, 'Kevin' ,'M', '2000/08/12' , '75 E Hall' , 5157082497 , '89 National' ,7182340772);

-- Insertion Record for departmetns table.
insert into departments values (401,'Computer Science',5152982801,'LAS');
insert into departments values (402,'Mathematics',5152982802,'LAS');
insert into departments values (403,'Chemical Engineering',5152982803,'Engineering');
insert into departments values (404,'Landscape Architect',5152982804,'Design');

-- Insertion Record for degrees table.
insert into  degrees values ( 'Computer Science','BS',401);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Software Engineering','BS',401);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Computer Science','MS',401);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Computer Science','PhD',401);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Applied Mathematics','MS',402);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Chemical Engineering','BS',403);
insert into  degrees values ( 'Landscape Architect','BS',404);

-- courses
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (113, 'Spreadsheet', 'Microsoft Excel and Access', 3, 'Undergraduate', 401);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (311, 'Algorithm', 'Design and Analysis', 3, 'Undergraduate', 401);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (531, 'Theory of Computation', 'Theorem and Probability ', 3, 'Graduate', 401);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (363, 'Database', 'Design Principle', 3, 'Undergraduate', 401);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (412, 'Water Management', 'Water Management', 3, 'Undergraduate', 404);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (228, 'Special Topics', 'Interesting Topics about CE', 3, 'Undergraduate', 403);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES (101, 'Calculus', 'Limit and Derivative', 4, 'Undergraduate', 402);

-- Insertion Record for register table.
insert into register values (1001,363,'Fall2020',3);
insert into register values (1002,313,'Fall2020',4);
insert into register values (1003,228,'Fall2020',4);
insert into register values (1004,363,'Spring2021',3);
insert into register values (1005,531,'Spring2021',4);
insert into register values (1006,363,'Fall2020',3);
insert into register values (1007,531,'Spring2021',4);

-- major
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1001, 'Computer Science', 'BS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1002, 'Software Engineering', 'BS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1003, 'Chemical Engineering', 'BS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1004, 'Landscape Architect', 'BS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1005, 'Computer Science', 'MS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1006, 'Applied Mathematics', 'MS');
INSERT INTO major VALUES (1007, 'Computer Science', 'PhD');

-- Minor
INSERT INTO minor VALUES (1007, 'Applied Mathematics', 'MS');
INSERT INTO minor VALUES (1005, 'Applied Mathematics', 'MS');
INSERT INTO minor VALUES (1001, 'Software Engineering', 'BS');
```

My error message:

**[23000][1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`university`.`register`, CONSTRAINT `register_student_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`snum`) REFERENCES `students` (`snum`))**

Comment: You can't insert into the `register` a `snum` that doesn't exist in the `students` table. Good use of composite primary keys. Welcome to SO. Please also see https://dba.stackexchange.com for purely database questions.

Comment: I have checked those values one after the other, but they seem to be present to the parent tables, but what is wrong with it???

Answer (score 2):

What is Foreign Key `snum` or `ssn`

```
if FOREIGN KEY is `ssn` then values in (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, ...)
if FOREIGN KEY is `snum` then values in (654651234, 123097834, 978012431, ...)
```

Besides the Insert code to table should be Lowercase `"students" not "Students"`

You can try:

```
insert into register values (654651234,363,'Fall2020',3);
```

or fix your code:

```
CREATE TABLE register
(
    ssn integer,
    course_number integer,
    regtime       varchar(20),
    grade         integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (snum, course_number),
    CONSTRAINT register_student_fk FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES students (ssn),
    CONSTRAINT register_courses_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_number) REFERENCES courses (number)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the Students typo, but I am still having the same problem. snum = student number and ssn = social security number. I don't know if this is a good response to your question

Comment: you can try "insert into register values (654651234,363,'Fall2020',3);"

Comment: you code "insert into register values (1001,363,'Fall2020',3);" . But There is no 1001 in the column "snum" students table.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. I am working on it

Comment: You’re welcome =))

Comment: Now, it's all good thanks

Comment: [~slash], welcome to Stack Overflow. Please accept the answers like this that have helped put you resolve and understand your question.